# Could questions asking for job advice for a group of people be considered on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

One of the reasons questions asking for advice about which jobs should they go for are marked as off topic are they aren't relevant to many people, if anyone except the original poster.

However I have come across [one question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23155/jobs-that-suit-disabled-workers) (that I did flag for this very reason) that seems to consider a group of people, in this case disabled people in general. As this question is relevant to a wider range of people could it, and others like it, be considered on topic?

I think the question to answer is does the question reach a wide enough range of people to be considered helpful and a good question. I think in answering that we'll automatically answer my other question of whether the specific question should be on topic. However I don't know how to judge that, so I'm asking those of you who have much more experience in this matter.

Answer (score 5):

This question makes me think of a similar one on Aviation Meta:
https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309/would-recommend-me-an-aircraft-for-this-mission-questions-be-appropriate

Basically, you will get a lot of answers that will be valid and correct, but no one answer will be the best or the most correct.  And that's why it doesn't fit the Q/A format of the site.

Comment: that makes sense to me. As opposed to [other close voters](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23155/jobs-that-suit-disabled-workers "see, my name isn't listed under 'specific reason' there"), my vote was for [too broad](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: I hadn't even thought about it from that angle.